# C++ splitting args by space, but dont split values with spaces

Tags: c++, string, boost

I have a command line argument as following string

```
"-opt1 val1 -opt2 val1 val2 -opt3 val3"
```

When I use boost split by space, result will be following

```
boost::split(target_vector, inputString, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);

["-opt1", "val1", "-opt2", "val1", "val2", "-opt3", "val3"]
```

I would rather like result to be

```
["-opt1", "val1", "-opt2", "val1 val2", "-opt3", "val3"]
```

I can write some logic around encountering - but wanted to see if theer was some built in way to do it.

Comment: Could you not perform the split as is, and then go through the results concatenating adjacent strings that do not start with `-`?

Comment: doesnt the boost command line parser work? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: The parser behaves as expected. I would strongly advice considering leaving the parser as is and fix the provided arguments instead, i.e. `-opt2 "val1 val2"` or `-opt2 val1\ val2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a generic string split function (tokenizer) the string can be split to generate output like this :

```
option : opt1 val1
  option name = opt1
  - value : val1
option : opt2 val1 val2
  option name = opt2
  - value : val1 val2
option : opt3 val3
  option name = opt3
  - value : val3
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>

// a generic string splitting algorithm (tokenizer)
// string_views are used so there will be no string copies involved.
auto split(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters, std::size_t maximum_number_of_substrings = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max())
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;

    if (string.size() == 0ul)
    {
        return substrings;
    }

    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        maximum_number_of_substrings--;
        if (maximum_number_of_substrings != 0ul)
        {
            end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));
        }
        else
        {
            end_pos = max_length;
        }

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}

int main()
{
    // demo command line
    // note I do NOT check for validity of the input string right now
    // this is a quick sketch of the approach.
    std::string command_line{ "-opt1 val1 -opt2 val1 val2 -opt3 val3" };

    // first create a vector of string_views based on splitting by "-"
    auto options = split(command_line, "-");

    // then each of those split substrings can be split by a space " "
    for (const auto& option : options)
    {
        std::cout << "option : " << option << "\n";

        auto values = split(option, " ", 2ul);

        // the first split value will be the option name
        std::cout << "  option name = " << values[0] << "\n";

        // the other substrings will be the values 
        for (std::size_t n{ 1ul }; n < values.size(); ++n)
        {
            std::cout << "  - value : " << values[n] << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed a couple of minor typos. I was tempted to change the instances of `if (foo.size() == 0)` to `if (foo.empty())`, but decided that was substantive enough it should probably left to you to decide whether you want that or not.

Comment: I think std::vector<>'s `empty()` should have been called `is_empty()`. I always thing of empty() a emptying the vector, so I tend to use the `.size()==0` as not to confuse myself. But in the end it's all the same.

Comment: Here they're dealing with `string_view`s, not `vector`s though (not that it makes a huge difference).

Comment: Me bad, I typed vector, I meant string_view. But it is the same naming thing ;)

Comment: Thankfully that sort of thing never, ever happens to me. Nope, definitely not! :-)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks, looks like I have to join all the values to get required output.

Comment: @PitDigger That would be very inefficient, I slightly adjusted the split function so you can specify a maximum amount of substrings. This will stop splitting if the maximum amount of substrings has been reached. This will give you the requested output, answer updated.